# NSManagedObject stop updating

Tags: core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

In my model I have:
Product <<---> Order

Product Attributes:
    productName
    productPrice
Product Relationships:
    order

Order Attributes:
    orderName
    salePerson
Order Relationships:
    products

Imagine I have a Product (call it product1):
productName: MacBook
productPrice: 1200

The application in general used to sale products.
So after add and done the sale. Automatically create an Order (call it currentOrder) which contain product1.

> [currentOrder addProductsObject:product1];

Next I changed product1 price to:
productPrice: 1000

After I recheck the product inside the currentOrder, I'll see the productPrice is UPDATED to: 1000
Which I need to not change and still be exactly like the previous (1200).

Basically I would to do something do NOT update the previous object.

Comment: Still it is not clear. What are you trying to achieve? You've updated property and you see result. What is wrong here?

Comment: product1 their price used to 1200. After I change the product1 the new price which 1000 effect the previous data which I don't want to effect that.

Comment: If you want to discard your latest changes just refresh produst1 [context refreshObject:product1 mergeChanges:NO]

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I think I couldn't explain my issue very well. 1- create order1 with product1 price 1200. 2- change product1 price to 1000. 3- create order2 with product1 price 1000. Now I want to have: order1 product1 price be 1200 and order2 product1 price be 1000

Comment: You have to create a different object `product2` for `order2`.

Comment: oh I understand you. Your business model is not suitable for your case. You need to have another entity 'Sale' or so. Your model should look like: Order <--->>Sale, Product <---> Sale. Product Attributes: productName. Order Attributes: orderName salePerson Order Relationships: sales. Save Attributes: productPrice Sale Relationships: order. So in this way you decouple price from product and will be able  store different prices in different orders.

Comment: Thanks. I think you are right. I though maybe not need that Sale. But you are saying in need that. Anyway thanks for your comment.

Comment: @MarkKryzhanouski: Yes, I just thought of the same solution. Why don't you post this as an answer? (Perhaps it should be Product <-->> Sale, otherwise each product can be sold only once!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your business model is not suitable for your case. You need to have another entity 'Sale' or so. Your model should look like: Order <--->>Sale, Product <---> Sale. Product Attributes: productName. Order Attributes: orderName salePerson Order Relationships: sales. Save Attributes: productPrice Sale Relationships: order. So in this way you decouple price from product and will be able store different prices in different orders.